# SQL sentence doesn't work with mybatis 3.3.2

Tags: mybatis

I have to duplicate registers in a lot of tables, to do so i've created a simple mybatis configuration like:

```
<insert id="copy" parameterType="hashmap" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id">
  INSERT INTO ${table}
    <foreach item="key" collection="keys" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        ${key}
    </foreach>
    VALUES
    <foreach item="key" collection="map" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        ${key}
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

So the approach is to select a row, change keys and some more elements in Java code and then insert it. But if fails with this trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:  Invalid argument(s) in call
### SQL: INSERT INTO XYZ      (           ... )
### Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Invalid argument
; SQL []; Argumento(s) no válido(s) en la llamada; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:  Invalid argument(s) in call
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:241)
```

But if i copy the SQL from the logs and execute it in SQLDeveloper, it works, how is that?

Comment: isn't DuplicateKeyException an hint ?  and  better use `#{key}` to bind parameters values instead of appending them to the SQL string, it will avoid SQL injection and handle type issues.

Comment: DuplicateKeyException is a database error. As for using #, the name of the columns are strings and not eligible for SQL injection, the values types are handled by code, bear in mind it's a generic method to deal with different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the ojdbc6dms_g.jar oracle driver instead of the regular ojdbc6.jar, i could debug with symbols and noticed it was searching for an 'id' column that i introduced with `keyColumn="id"`, i removed it and worked since